# Parsing txt file and search for specific word

Tags: java, file, io

I have the following text fil, I'm wondering how can I parse it and search for Cell And Engine words, what I want is to print out the method name that contains Cell, Engine words. the following is the txt file don't look at it as java code since I already moved it to txt file for parsing purposes.

```
@Test
  public void testGetMonsters() {
        Cell cell11 = aBoard.getCell(1, 1);
        theEngine = new Engine(theGame);   
  }

  @Test
  public void testDxDyPossibleMove() {
        Cell cell11 = aBoard.getCell(1, 1);
  }
```

The desired output of parsing looks like:

```
testGetMonsters class contains Cell and Engine words
testDxDyPossibleMove class contains Cell word
```

Comment: This is confusing.  Can you clarify your problem and question a bit?

Comment: How is this different from the first time you asked?

Comment: @Dave you didn't answer in both questions so thanks for your comments, I tried here to simplify the question

Comment: @Ma please don't put all the typos I removed back into your question. [txt, pars, Engin]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tadaaaa!

```
package textsearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class TextSearch {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final URL testFileURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("textsearch/test.txt");
        final File input = new File(testFileURL.toURI());
        final FileReader reader = new FileReader(input);

        final SearchString search1 = new SearchString("Cell");
        final SearchString search2 = new SearchString("Engine");

        final List<SearchString> searches = new ArrayList<SearchString>();
        searches.add(search1);
        searches.add(search2);

        final Search search = new Search(searches);

        try {
            search.search(reader);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

        if(search.hasPositives()) {
            System.out.print("File " + input.getName() + " contains the words ");
            search.printPositives();
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File " + input.getName() + " didn't contain any of the search terms.");
        }

    }

    private static class SearchString {

        final String searchString;
        final ParsePosition pos;

        SearchString(final String searchString) {

            if(searchString == null || searchString.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("I can't search for nothing!");

            this.searchString = searchString;
            pos = new ParsePosition(0);

        }

        boolean checkNextChar(final char c) {

            if(searchString.charAt(pos.getIndex()) == c) {
                pos.setIndex(pos.getIndex() + 1);
                if(pos.getIndex() >= searchString.length()) {
                    pos.setIndex(0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                pos.setIndex(0);
                return false;
            }

        }

        String getString() {

            return searchString;

        }

    }

    private static class Search {

        private final List<SearchString> searches;
        private final List<SearchString> positives;

        Search(final List<SearchString> searches) {

            this.searches = searches;
            positives = new ArrayList<SearchString>();

        }

        void search(final Reader reader) throws IOException {

            int current;

            while((current = reader.read()) != -1 && !searches.isEmpty()) {

                char c = (char)current;

                for(final Iterator<SearchString> it = searches.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    final SearchString searchString = it.next();
                    final boolean matches = searchString.checkNextChar(c);
                    if(matches) {
                        positives.add(searchString);
                        it.remove();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        boolean hasPositives() {

            return !positives.isEmpty();

        }

        void printPositives() {

            for(final Iterator<SearchString> it = positives.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                final SearchString searchString = it.next();
                System.out.print(searchString.getString());
                if(it.hasNext())
                    System.out.print(", ");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Alright, it ain't 100% reliable, but it's a start.

EDIT: or you can use a Scanner like KayKay suggested, but where's the fun in that :D

Comment: when I added the resource of the txt file    final URL testFileURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("C:/Desktop/test.txt");  it gives me this error --> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at textsearch.TextSearch.main(TextSearch.java:18)

Comment: Yeah, that thing assumes the text.txt file is in the textsearch package, next to the class. Using `File("C:/Desktop/test.txt")` would suffice in your case. I didn't bother with clean code, the SearchString and Search classes are all that's important.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not familiar with these stuff, you are awesome but the problem is you are searching inside the whole file what I need is to specify where these words are (in which class), like this :        testGetMonsters class contains Cell and Engine words
testDxDyPossibleMove class contains Cell word

Comment: Just get readers for the Java source files and pass each one into a new Search object with the desired SearchStrings. If you remove the `it.remove()` you can reuse the same Search object. Unless you mean you only have the compiled classes. That won't work, you'd need the source code.

Comment: @Ma Wait, I just checked your original post again. You want to know which **methods** these words appear in? Those are methods, not classes! You'd need something that's aware of Java language constructs for that, like the mirror API. That's a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: yes these are methods sorry for misconvenience, what you said is what I want exactly, you are the first one who got my point finally

Comment: Then Jeff Ferland's suggestion is the best so far. Use a lexer for parsing the text in a language-aware fashion. Won't be simple, but I don't know of any ready-to-use solution. Why exactly do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: I'm working on a big project and almost done with it, I just need to get this information dynamically by using java but I'm not familiar at all with java just a beginner, I'm using modeling oriented languages in my project, Thanks once again Dear G_H

Comment: Last comment since this is becoming too long outside of chat: since IDEs like Eclipse and NetBeans offer searches for classes by use, maybe there's some stuff you can rip out of their code base for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use regular expressions and the pattern matching facility of Java. Take a look at [Regular Expressions and the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/) for example usage.

Quick example:

```
Pattern cellPattern = Pattern.compile("Cell");
    while (fileReader.ready()) {
        String inputLine = fileReader.readLine();
        Matcher cellMatcher = cellPattern.matcher(inputLine);
        if(cellMatcher.lookingAt()) {
            //This line contains the word "Cell"
```

Determining if / what class you're in is another question... you'll need a "lexer" for that. [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) is a good starting point there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the link between your code and your question but :

```
String text = new Scanner(yourFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
String wordsToLookFor = Arrays.asList("cell", "engine");

List<String> wordsContained = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String word : wordsToLookFor){
  if(text.contains(word)) {
     wordsContained.add(word);
  }
}

System.out.println(yourFile.getName() + " contains " + wordsContained);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure I understand your question here are some tips.

To get class name use `obj.getClass().getName()`.
To search into string use str.contains("Cell") or use regular expressions. Take a look on class `java.util.Pattern`.